# R: unable to install gbm.auto package from Github

Tags: r, github, install.packages

I'm trying to install the package **gbm.auto** via github, but the download does not seem to work. How can I solve this? I am working on a windows 10 Pro (R version 3.6.1, Rstudio version 1.2.5042). This is the error I get:

> remotes::install_github("SimonDedman/gbm.auto")

```
Downloading GitHub repo SimonDedman/gbm.auto@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Ststrubb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOcwGGZ\remotes1d5c7c774f2a\SimonDedman-gbm.auto-96328bf/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'gbm.auto': (359ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'gbm.auto_1.2.4.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ststrubb/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'gbm.auto' ...
** using staged installation
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  C:/Users/Ststrubb/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpALsbRt/R.INSTALL7320575e5a03/gbm.auto/R/gbm.valuemap.R:462:0: unexpected end of input
460: beep(8)} # notify user & close function
461: 
    ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'gbm.auto'
* removing 'C:/Users/***/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/gbm.auto'
Error: Failed to install 'gbm.auto' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOcwGGZ/file1d5c40b85311/gbm.auto_1.2.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get the same error when I used
**githubinstall** or **remotes::install_github**.

Comment: Solved. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364853/error-in-parseoutfile-unexpected-end-of-input-bug-in-package-install-and) (but actually just retry install).

Comment: Ah great! Thank you so much