# Error in parse(outFile) : unexpected end of input - bug in package install, and how to fix

Tags: r, parsing, compiler-errors, package, installation

In trying to install my own package from GitHub I hit a problem that others have notified me about and I'd tried unsuccessfully to fix. I conclude that the package installer misinforms the user about the problem source, leading to fruitless searching for faults in working scripts.

```
install_github("SimonDedman/gbm.auto", force = TRUE)
```

[image: screenshot]

(Screenshot so it lines up properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bill Dunlap has now provided a patch proposal on the R bugzilla (R's issue tracker), mentioned above:  bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17859#c4
and we (R Core) are looking into it.
It *is* true that parsing all source files separately is more expensive,
notably only for packages that are "pure R" (no compilation) and also don't do other expensive things.
Still, we agree the package developer should get a more useful error in such cases, and we also agree that syntactically the R/*.R source files should be self contained  (i.e., *not* opening a brace in one file and closing it in a following one !!)

Comment: Bill Dunlap's patch has now been committed to the R sources (for R version >= 4.3.0 from ca. April 2023 on), together with regr.checks and NEWS, in  svn rev 83640 (visible at mirror https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/commit/b6b785d945a680c41c16fd6418332e797fbd68c4

Answer (score 2):

One would logically conclude that the problem is... where the console says it is - the end of this file, gbm.valuemap_oldbkup.R. But I have *scoured* that file. It's fine. Reverted to a historical version (hence oldbkup filename) and that's fine too. BUT: instead of the error being in gbm.valuemap.R, now it's in gbm.valuemap_oldbkup.R. The difference? Oldbkup is now the last file in the list. So maybe the problem isn't that this specific file has an unclosed bracket... it's that there's an unclosed bracket somewhere in any of the previous files. Extending [Duncan Murdoch's approach](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/unable-to-collate-and-parse-R-files-for-package-unexpected-end-of-input-td4690788.html):

```
setwd("gbm.auto/R/") # goto package root
allfiles <- list.files() # list files
for (i in allfiles) {
  print(paste0(which(allfiles %in% i), "/", length(allfiles), " : ", i)) # counter
  text <- readLines(i)
  src <- srcfile(i)
  parse(text = text, srcfile = src)
}
```

I find that the problem is actually in gbm.auto.R. I scour that file, find the problem, fix it, retry install, works fine. I'll find out where to file this bug (install_packages, R, RStudio, other) and do so. In the meantime, hopefully this helps others.

Comment: This is because you can open a brace in one file, and close it in a different file.  So a missing closing brace shows up when you get to the end of the last file without finding a match.  It would make more sense to require that each file is syntactically complete, but that's not what R does.

Comment: I've opened a bug in remotes (install_packages) proposing the per-file approach. Seems to me the real problem is that the error message helper sends the user the wrong way, which can be less useful than not suggesting a reason at all.

Comment: I think this is an R issue rather than a `remotes` issue, but they could probably do the parsing a second time and give a better message.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the intel. I'll see if they respond to my issue and push it up the chain if they think that's the best avenue.

Comment: not a remotes issue: https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/507
filed R bug: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17859

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by updating R to the newest version (4.2+).